# Installing clang and LLVM binaries on OS X

Tags: clang, llvm

I've downloaded the clang binaries for OS X from http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.3.  Where am I supposed to put them?

Comment: Clang and LLVM comes bundled with XCode, is there a reason for you not using these binaries?

Comment: Generelly, it doesn't really matter as long as you know where you put them. If you want other tools (Cmake, e.g.) to find it, the location should be in your path variable. You could put them into `/usr/bin`, e.g. What are you going to do with Clang? Just manual builds from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Clang and LLVM comes bundled with Apples XCode. To get XCode, which includes Clang, llvm and more, get it from the Mac appstore per instructions on https://developer.apple.com/xcode/.

`clang` and multiple `llvm-` commands should then be available in `/usr/bin`

Comment: I think you need to install the Command Line Tools (this can be triggered within Xcode) to have `clang` available in `/usr/bin`. Otherwise, it is in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`.